# Set Select Options Equal To MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a sql query and returning results, how can I set a select list equal to the query results?  Here is my syntax, but I am not sure how to associate the returned results to the select?

By default I want the select to have a null value.

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "dbTest";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }
  $sql = "Select CONCAT_WS(' ', name1, name2) As 'employeeName' from employees";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['employeename'] ."<br>"; }
  } 
  $conn->close();
?>  

<html>
    <body>
       <h4>Opening Header</h4>
        <form> 
          <select> 
            <option>Set this to $result</option>
          </select> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT --- so $result will contain values like

> Bob Jones 
>   Mitch Sandberg 
>   Jose Mintz

And I would want all 3 of those to be a different value to pick from in the select.

Comment: `echo $row['FullName']` should be `echo $row['employeeName']`

Comment: @Fabio good catch.  I have edited.

Comment: It isn't clear how the `<select>` is to function. Is it intended to have multiple `<option>`, one for each row of `$result`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski check out my edit and see if that clarifies

Comment: You probably want to pull the employeeid as well, otherwise if two employees have the same name you wont be able to distinguish. Populate the result to an array then iterate through it in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just place the php script after the select tag and put option tag on the echo inside the loop.

```
<html>
<body>
   <h4>Opening Header</h4>
    <form> 
      <select> 
      <option value="null" selected="selected">Default</option>
          <?php
         $servername = "localhost";
          $username = "username";
          $password = "password";
          $dbname = "dbTest";
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
          if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }
          $sql = "Select CONCAT_WS(' ', name1, name2) As 'employeeName' from employees";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);

          if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
          {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<option value=".$row['employeename'].">".$row['employeename']."</option><br>"; }
          } 
          $conn->close();
        ?>
      </select> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This sets the query results to the select list but it is not defaulting to a null value.  I want the 1st option to always be a null value.(Actually null isn't even an option)

Comment: So place an empty `<option></option>` after `<select>`, before the script.

Comment: @Sebastianofranceschin - with your current syntax it will write the text "Default" for a NULL value.  I just removed that text and it presents a text free NULL value as the default option.

Comment: i just added that "default" text as a placeholder, you can put whatever you need to put or let it blank if is this what you need.